# GET Collection By Type or String

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, system.reflection

I am using reflection to dynamically generate forms in my application.  When dealing with properties that have relationships I need to be able to dynamically call a collection.

How can I replace:

```
foreach (Customer c in Db.Customers)
{

}
```

With something like this:

```
foreach (dynamic d in Db["Customers"])
{

}
```

or like this

```
foreach (dynamic d in Db.typeof(Customer))
{

}
```

Comment: In your examples, what is the data type of `Db`?

Comment: I was able to achieve this through the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910340/how-to-get-dbset-from-entity-name-in-ef-core-net-core-2-0

Comment: @TomCrosman Please, close your question as duplicate then

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
foreach (dynamic d in (DB.GetType().GetProperty("Customers")).GetValue(DB, null)){
}
```

In more understandable way

```
var propertyInfo = DB.GetType().GetProperty("Customers");
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(DB, null);
```