# Change DbSet with table name

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I would like to know how to change DbSet on a DbContext using a table name (instead of using a fix DbSet as in the example). I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305737/how-do-i-select-correct-dbset-in-dbcontext-based-on-table-name) but with no results.

```
        var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == tablename);

        DbSet dsContext = DbContext.Set(type);

        var data = DbContext.dsContext 
            .Where(r => r.C_NUMERICID == idLinea)
            .Where(r => r.C_TIMESTAMP > startDate)
            .OrderBy(r => r.C_TIMESTAMP)
            .ToList();
```

> DbContext does not contain the defintion of 'dsContext'

Comment: `but with no results.` Tell us more about what you mean by that.

Comment: @mjwills edited

Comment: I do have two derived types         

`public virtual DbSet<IMA> IMA { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<SEZIONATRICE> SEZIONATRICE { get; set; }` With tablename == 'SEZIONATICE' I get that error

Comment: why don't just you write `var data = dsContext.Where(r => r.C_NUMERICID == idLinea) ...` ?

Comment: why 2 votes for closing my question? Bad quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was querying wrong. This is the working solution.

```
type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetTypes()
   .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == kepwareTableName);
IQueryable data = DbContext.Set(type)
   .Where($"C_NUMERICID == {idLinea}")
   .Where("C_TIMESTAMP > @0", startDate)
   .OrderBy("C_TIMESTAMP");
return data ;
```