# EF 6 - How to get DbSet by table name

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dbcontext

I have a DbContext that looks like this:

```
 public partial class MyDbConnectionConnection : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbConnectionConnection()
            : base("name=MyDbConnectionConnection ")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Name> tbName{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Surname> tbSurname{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> tbAddress{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Currency> tbCurrency { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and I need to search through this Context and find data set that matches the table name for example:

```
   public dynamic getCorrectEntity()
    {
        MyDbConnectionConnection Context = new MyDbConnectionConnection();
        var dbset = Context.Set(Type.GetType("tbName"));

        return dbset;
    }
```

where "tbName" is name of DbSet.

I cannot get anything!

In this line of code Type.GetType("tbName") it returns value null.

I just need to mentioned that I googled, try all examples I found here in the last couple of hours but nothing helps :(

Does anyone know how to get entity on this way?

P.S. I also try all this using Assembly.GetType(name). It didn't help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select correct DbSet in DbContext based on table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305737/how-do-i-select-correct-dbset-in-dbcontext-based-on-table-name)

Comment: I saw that and try everything that people suggested, it didn't work...

Comment: The string you have to pass must be the name of the type. So for `DbSet<Name> tbName { get; set; }` you have to pass `"Name"`, not `"tbName"`.

Comment: Thank you, I try this too, but Type.GetType("Name") also returns null ...

Comment: `var dbset = Context.GetType().GetProperty("tbName").GetValue(Context)`