# How do I fix `System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1 not found.`?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, dbset

#### Database Table Export to CSV using EntityFramework DbContext .NET 6

I have been tasked to create a Blazor ASP.NET Core application that will export each table from an MS SQL Server database into it's own `.csv` file.  I have extracted the `DbSets` from the `DbContext` properties into a generic list, but when I attempt to cast the generic objects to their `DbSet` class I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> MissingMethodException: Constructor on type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[[DatabaseTableExport.Data.LoginDbModels.AccountPasswordHistory,
> DatabaseTableExport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
> binder, object[] args, CultureInfo culture)

How do I fix this error, or is there a better way to be extracting the `DbSets` from the `DbContext`?

```
using DatabaseTableExport.Data;
using DatabaseTableExport.Data.LoginDbModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DatabaseTableExport.Pages
{
    public partial class Index : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        private LoginDbContext LoginDbContext { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        private ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            List<DbSet<object>> dbSets = GetDbSets(LoginDbContext);

            // iterate through each DbSet instance
            foreach (var dbSet in dbSets)
            {
                // export to csv here
            }

        }

        private static List<DbSet<object>> GetDbSets(DbContext loginDbContext)
        {
            // Retrieve all the DbSet properties declared on the context class.
            var dbSetProperties = loginDbContext.GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
                .ToList();

            // Iterate over each DbSet property and add it to the list of dbsets.
            var dbSets = new List<DbSet<object>>();
            foreach (var property in dbSetProperties)
            {
                // If the type of the DbSet is null, skip it.
                if (property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Length <= 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Get the generic type arguments and create a corresponding DbSet instance.
                var dbsetGenericType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
                var convertedDbSet = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(dbsetGenericType), property.GetValue(loginDbContext));

                dbSets.Add((DbSet<object>)convertedDbSet);
            }

            // Return the list of DbSet objects.
            return dbSets;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: What is the reason of doing that? For sure it is wrong. `GetDbSets` has no sense without explanation.

Comment: `GetDbSets ` is defined and included with the code above. It is the method that gets the `DbSets` and returns them so they can be used to export the data to a `.csv` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest different approach. EF Core works without `DbContext` properties. Metadata information can be retrieved from DbContext's Model and Export can be initiated via CallBack.

Callback interface:

```cs
public interface IRecordsetProcessor
{
    void ProcessRecordset<T>(DbContext context, IQueryable<T> recordset, IEntityType entityType)
        where T: class;
}
```

Recordset enumeration Implemantation:

```cs
public static class DbContextUtils
{
    public static void ProcessRecordset<T>(DbContext context, IEntityType entityType, IRecordsetProcessor processor) 
        where T : class
    {
        processor.ProcessRecordset(context, context.Set<T>(), entityType);
    }

    private static MethodInfo _processMethod = typeof(DbContextUtils).GetMethod(nameof(ProcessRecordset))!;

    public static void ProcessRecordsets(DbContext context, IRecordsetProcessor processor)
    {
        var entityTypes = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .Where(et => !et.IsOwned())
            .ToList();

        foreach (var et in entityTypes)
        {
            _processMethod.MakeGenericMethod(et.ClrType).Invoke(null, new object[] { context, et, processor });
        }
    }
}
```

Simple sample implementation of export:

```cs
public class ExportProcessor : IRecordsetProcessor
{
    private const string ColumnSeparator = ",";

    static string PreparePropertyValue(IProperty prop, object record)
    {
        var clrValue = prop.GetGetter().GetClrValue(record);

        // without converter
        var value = clrValue;

        // with converter
        /*
        var converter = prop.GetValueConverter();
        var value = converter == null ? clrValue : converter.ConvertToProvider(clrValue);
        */
        
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        var strValue = value.ToString() ?? "";

        if (strValue.Contains(ColumnSeparator) || strValue.Contains('\"'))
        {
            strValue = "\"" + strValue.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
        }

        return strValue;
    }

    public void ProcessRecordset<T>(DbContext context, IQueryable<T> recordset, IEntityType entityType) where T : class
    {
        var exportItems = new List<string>();
        var properties = entityType.GetProperties().ToList();

        // produce header
        exportItems.Add(string.Join(ColumnSeparator, properties.Select(p => p.GetColumnName())));

        foreach (var record in recordset.AsNoTracking())
        {
            exportItems.Add(string.Join(ColumnSeparator, properties.Select(p => PreparePropertyValue(p, record))));
        }

        // TODO: save to file, or do that without intermediate list
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```cs
DbContextUtils.ProcessRecordsets(context, new ExportProcessor());
```

Comment: I like this approach, unfortunately it has me back to the same problem of how to now access the data in the individual objects of result.  I need to be able to cast them as a DbSet object or some access the data in some other way. With your solution I can iterate through each result object, but the object itself is not yet useful and when I attempt to cast to a DbSet object I still get an error. To complete the solution, how do I access the data in each object of the result?

Comment: `var result = q.OfType<object>().ToList();` is not solution?

Comment: No that still gives back a generic List<T>. If I do something like `var foreach (var result in results) { var table = LoginDbContext.Set(result.GetType()); }` It doesn't work because the type cannot be inferred.

Comment: Both the way you suggest, and the way I am using gets the list of the DbSets from the DbContext, but both throw an error when anything is done with the list of objects to convert them into a usable type.

Comment: Then use `ExportData` function itself. It is generic.

Comment: Thanks again Svyatoslav, will you please provide a reference link to more information or updated the code with an example? I have not been able to find the `ExporData` method you mentioned or anything about it yet.

Comment: `public static void ExportData<T>` - in this answer.

Comment: Again, thank you. Please excuse me for not being clear, I am still not able to use the `ExportData` method that you have given. Please add a code example for the use of `ExportData` method to your answer.

Comment: Please add your export code. I do not understand what you are trying to do and how.

Comment: I need to export each table from an MS SQL Server database into its own .csv file. I haven't written that code yet because it is only a `string` (or series of `strings`) being saved to a `filestream`.

Comment: Do it right now [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25684175/10646316)

Comment: We have a utility we built for team so for this type of thing so it is always done the same way. It is a "spreadsheet" or "csv" file export utility that accepts a `List` of `strings` where the first `string` in the `List` are the column headers. The remaining strings in the list are the rows of data.  What I am working to produce is a `List<string>` for each `Table` from the database that follows this format.

Comment: @TysonGibby, slightly changed implementation, and even added generation of CSV records.

Comment: Svyatoslav, I need to do something very similar but a little different. Can't figure out how to save data back to the records. Love you get your input if you have the opportunity to take a look. This is the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241068/how-to-update-the-property-value-database-field-of-t-entity-database-table-f